# Getting java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/xerces/dom/ElementNSImpl with Apache ODF Toolkit

Tags: java, odf, odfdom

I am trying to read an `ods` file using `Apache ODF Toolkit`. I am getting `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError` error while while trying to load the Spreadsheet using below code-

```
SpreadsheetDocument data = SpreadsheetDocument.loadDocument(file);
```

Below is the error trace-

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/xerces/dom/ElementNSImpl
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at test.read.ODSFile.ReadODS.main(ReadODS.java:33)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.xerces.dom.ElementNSImpl
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 25 more
```

Below is the project structure, which shows the classpath-
[image: Eclipse screenshot]

Is there any dependencies missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems your code can not find the class:
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.xerces.dom.ElementNSImpl

from [ODF Toolkit](http://incubator.apache.org/odftoolkit/xsltrunner/ODFXSLTRunner.html)

*Note: ODFDOM requires Apache Xerces. The jar file xercesImpl.jar also must exist in a folder lib next to odfxsltrunner.jar file, or it must be in the classpath. The ODF XSLT Runner NetBeans projects includes a reference to xersesImpl.jar in the runtime classpath which has to be adapted after checking out the project.*